# Improve performance of masking followed by weighted average

Tags: python, performance, numpy

The function `func()` defined below is buried deep inside a Markov Chain Monte Carlo process which means it is called millions of times. I need to improve its performance as much as possible, but I haven't found a way to do it.

The definition of the mask (`msk`) and the weighted average take up approximately the same portion of time. Probably there's no way to obtain the weighted average faster than how `numpy` is doing it, but could the mask definition be improved at least?

```
def func(weights, x1, x2, x3, x4):
    for x in (x2, x3, x4):
        # Mask of the distance between the column '-6' of x1 versus arrays
        # x2,x3,x4
        msk = abs(x1[-6] - x[-6]) > 0.01
        # If the distance in this array is larger than the maximum allowed,
        # mask with the values taken from 'x1'.
        x[:, msk] = x1[:, msk]

    # Weighted average for all the arrays.
    avrg_data = np.average(np.array([x1, x2, x3, x4]), weights=weights, axis=0)

    return avrg_data


# Random data with proper shape
x1, x2, x3, x4 = np.random.uniform(1., 10., (4, 10, 1000))
weights = np.random.uniform(0.01, .5, 4)

# Call many times and time it
s = t.time()
for _ in range(10000):
    func(weights, x1, x2, x3, x4)
print(t.time() - s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with your code and happened to try if doing the weighted average directly without using np.average would be quicker, and it looks like it is. On my platform it is about 40% faster.

```
import time as t
import numpy as np

def func(weights, x1, x2, x3, x4):
    for x in (x2, x3, x4):
        # Mask of the distance between the column '-6' of x1 versus arrays
        # x2,x3,x4
        msk = abs(x1[-6] - x[-6]) > 0.01

        # If the distance in this array is larger than the maximum allowed,
        # mask with the values taken from 'x1'.
        x[:, msk] = x1[:, msk]

    # Weighted average for all the arrays.
    avrg_data = np.average(np.array([x1, x2, x3, x4]), weights=weights, axis=0)

    return avrg_data

def faster_func(weights, x1, x2, x3, x4):
    for x in (x2, x3, x4):
        # Mask of the distance between the column '-6' of x1 versus arrays
        # x2,x3,x4
        msk = abs(x1[-6] - x[-6]) > 0.01

        # If the distance in this array is larger than the maximum allowed,
        # mask with the values taken from 'x1'.
        x[:, msk] = x1[:, msk]

    # Scale weights so they add up to 1, then add based on them
    weights = weights / np.mean(weights) / 4    
    avrg_data = x1*weights[0] + x2*weights[1] + x3*weights[2] + x4*weights[3]

    return avrg_data

# Random data with proper shape
x1, x2, x3, x4 = np.random.uniform(1., 10., (4, 10, 1000))
weights = np.random.uniform(0.01, .5, 4)

# Call many times and time it
for method in (func, faster_func):
    s = t.time()
    for _ in range(10000):
        method(weights, x1, x2, x3, x4)
    print(method, t.time() - s)

# Test that the results are still the same
result1 = func(weights, x1, x2, x3, x4)
result2 = faster_func(weights, x1, x2, x3, x4)
biggest_difference = np.max(abs(result1-result2))
print("Biggest difference between two methods was %.8f" % biggest_difference)
```

Comment: I swear I tried obtaining the weighted average manually but I could not get any improvements. I must've done something wrong because your solution is ~60% faster on my system. It can be made even marginally faster using `weights = weights / np.sum(weights)` to scale the weights.